# How to manage plugins and plugins update?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mef

I'm trying to find best way to create extensible and autoupdating application.

Scenario:

- many standalone applications on clients machines
- dlls with plugins for those standalone applications are on one internal server for example in one directory

I'd like create applications which will connect to server, ask about plugins, download plugin, use it and if any update or any new plugin appeared, app should download update and replace/add/delete plugin.

I'd like to have something like centralised repository.

What is the best solution for this problem? I'm trying to use MEF to extend my application, but i don't know any tools/patterns for second stage - auto-updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the ClickOnce Deployment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I've read that i can apply this technology to WPF.WinForms/Console app. Right now i'm creating only a part of bigger application and i'd like to add auto-update feature just to this part not to the whole system - right now i'm not able to add this feature to the system. I'm interested in something which will be invoked when someone is going to use this part... After quick review I think this technology can't help me... Am I wrong?

Comment: "I'd like create applications which will connect to server, ask about plugins, download plugin, use it and if any update or any new plugin appeared, app should download update and replace/add/delete plugin." You can accomplish this by deploying your apps using ClickOnce, when you decide that you need to update a plugin or the whole app publish your changes to the ClickOnce site and the update process will be automated for all the installed apps.